# Why is VSCode Ctrl+Space suggesting all words, vice methods/attributes?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, intellisense, lint

Using `Ctrl+Space` while editing a python file triggers a suggestions popup. However, rather than linting the object and suggesting its methods/attributes, my popup shows me all words in the file (sorted alphabetically).

For instance, `10_000` and `10k` are just words listed in my script,  not methods attached to the `model` object's class:
[image: terrible suggestions from VSCode]

***Question:* How can I limit these suggestions to the relevant methods/attributes?**

It seems to me that Intellisense is treating my code as text, but I set the language mode to Python in VSCode.

Comment: Could you please add `"python.languageServer": "Pylance"` to your `settings.json`? Then try again.

Comment: you don't have a language provider set, you only get text suggestions (`abc` icon)